# Program does not seem to want to read from a file

Tags: c#, winforms

I was reading a binary file and while waiting for something to happen, I noticed that the program wasn't doing anything.

It seemed to be stuck at a certain point in execution. I added in some print statements to console, and can see that it gets to a certain point...but then doesn't seem to want to continue. This is the first couple lines of code:

```
private BinaryReader inFile;
public void Parser(string path)
{
    byte[] newBytes;
    newBytes =  File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.Write(newBytes, 0, newBytes.Length);
        inFile = new BinaryReader(ms);
        inFile.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
}

public void ParseFile()
{
  Console.WriteLine("parsing");
  Console.WriteLine("get size to read"); // prints this out
  int sizeToRead = inFile.ReadInt32();
  Console.WriteLine("Size: {0}", sizeToRead); // doesn't print this out
  Console.WriteLine("Done"); // end file processing
}
```

When I comment out the read, it works fine. I dumped the contents of `inFile` into a new file and it was the same as the original file, so it should be a valid stream.

I am not sure how to continue debugging this issue. Anyone ran into similar issues?

EDIT: Sorry, I was posting bits and pieces of different methods. Here's the whole methods

Comment: Yep agree @CodingGorilla going to need to know what `inFile` is, and could you include the code the for it?

Comment: Sorry, it's just a `BinaryReader`

Comment: I combined different methods together but didn't think about how it would turn out. I figured out what the problem was: turns out my memory stream had to be reset to position 0 because of how my stream was being done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you leave the `using` block, the `MemoryStream` is disposed, making your `BinaryReader` invalid as well. Throwing away the memory stream is pulling the rug out from under your binary reader. Move all of your related reading code into a using block, if you can, and wrap your `BinaryReader` in one as well.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))
using (var inFile = new BinaryReader(ms))
{
    inFile.ReadInt32();
}
```

You can read directly from the file as well, unless you have a reason to read it all in and feed it through a `MemoryStream`.

If the way your code is laid out keeps you from using `using`, then you can keep track of the `MemoryStream` and `BinaryReader` objects and implement `IDisposable`. Then call Dispose` on them later to clean up.

The garbage collector will clean up *eventually* if you don't do this, but calling `Dispose` on anything that is `IDisposable` is good habit to get into. If you don't, you may run into issues with open file handles or GDI objects sitting around in the finalizer queue waiting to be disposed.

Comment: no need to Dispose when wrapped in the using

Comment: Right. I only said to keep track of/dispose the stream and reader if you can't use `using` (such as in the example in the OP).

Comment: not a problem it reads a bit confusing.. but you have the upvote good answer by the way.. I will also upvote :)

Comment: Thanks :) I'll edit my answer to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a BinaryReader only like this instead of using FileStream also (if you are).
If this does not work, try other Encoding options like `Encoding.Unicode`.

```
        using (BinaryReader inFile = new BinaryReader(File.Open(@"myFile.dat", FileMode.Open),Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            int pos = 0;
            int length = (int)inFile.BaseStream.Length;
            int sizeToRead;
            while (pos < length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("get size to read"); // prints this out
                sizeToRead = inFile.ReadInt32();
                Console.WriteLine("Size: {0}", sizeToRead); // doesn't print this out, or anything after
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done"); // end file processing
        }
```

If that doesn't work, then try using `File.OpenRead` like this to avoid the possibility of the file being accessed in any other mode than Read:

```
using (BinaryReader inFile = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(@"myFile.dat"),Encoding.Unicode))
```